# Prove that the least upper bound of $A$ cannot be rational

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$ be defined by
$$
A=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:x^2<2\}.
$$

> Prove that $A$ cannot have a least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$.

I know I could prove that $\sqrt2$ is the least upper bound of $A$ and prove that $\sqrt2$ is irrational. However, I'm looking to prove this using an alternative method because it might not always be obvious what the least upper bound should be.

#### Initial thoughts

My initial thinking is to prove this by contradiction.

So, suppose $y\in\mathbb{Q}$ is the least upper bound of $A$. Then for any $z\in\mathbb{R}$ with $z<y$, we can find $a\in A$ such that $a>z$.

Since $a\in A$, we have that $a=m/n$ for some $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and that $a^2<2$. Similarly, since $y\in\mathbb{Q}$, we have that $y=p/q$ for some $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$.

#### Problem

I'm not sure how to combine these facts to construct a contradiction. Any hints/insights would be great.

Comment: In your "So, suppose..." statement I believe you need to prove that y is not in A for this. E.g. if we have $E = \{...,-1,0,1,...,25\}$, you can take plenty of real numbers between 24 and 25 not in this set. This is fine in your case, you would still have to prove $y\notin A$ though.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a function $f: [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ with the following properties:

- $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$,
- $f$ is increasing,
- $x < f(x) < 2$ if $x < 2$.

Thus for any proposed $a \in A$, we have

- $f(a) \in A$ and
- $f(a) > a$.

This shows that $a$ cannot be the supremum of $A$.

Can you find such a function? Spoiler below.

> The rational function
>  $$f(x) = \frac{4 + 3x}{3 + 2x}$$ works.
>
>  It is constructed as
>  $f(x) = g(g(x))$, where     $$g(x) = \frac{2 + x}{1 + x}$$
>  which also converges to $\sqrt{2}$ upon
>  iteration, but in an alternating manner.

Comment: Can you clarify your third condition? Is it a typo?

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's a copy-paste typo. I fixed it. Basically, $f$ a *contraction mapping*.

Comment: The function $f(x) = x/2$ will satisfy your conditions. However, it is not true that $f(a) > a$ for $ a \in A$.

Comment: Good point. I have a particular function in mind. I was trying to state it slightly more generally, but clearly I need more restrictive criteria. I will edit again. :-P

Comment: Yeah, I can't seem to make it work anymore. I haven't been active on math.SE in a while, and it used to work.

Comment: The devs changed how quotes & spoilers work last year, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919/334566  and there are still a few niggling corner cases. And then, a few months later,  they changed the Markdown engine. Also, there are some discrepancies with spoilers, between the full site view & the mobile view.

Comment: What about the case where $A$ has a supremum but that supremum is not an element of $A$?

Comment: I think the third condition should be "$x<f(x)<\sqrt{2}$ if $x<\sqrt{2}$" (or equivalently "$x^2<f(x)^2<2$ if $x^2<2$")

Comment: There is a problem here, as Daniel Schepler already mentioned: If you replace $A$ by $A=\{x\in\mathbb{Q} \mid x^2<4\}$ and $f$ by $f(x) = \frac{8+5x}{5+2x}$, this argument would "prove" that $A$ had no supremum in $\mathbb{Q}$, but this is false ($\sup A = 2$).